# Checking If against multiple values

Tags: stata

I'm using `ssc install vallist` to generate a list of applicable countries that outputs a macro something like:

r(list) : "32 36 348 392 410 76 112 152 156 203"
Optionally, this can be returned separated by commas instead of spaces if it's helpful)

I then want to `tab` a variable if it has a country that is anywhere in that list.

Any thoughts on how to do this.
I'd like to use inlist, but I'd have to pass each country in manually like this

```
Typing by hand works just fine
tab health if inlist(country, 32, 36, 348,... 203)

I'd like to do this
tab health if inlist(country, r(list))
```

Perhaps, is there any way I can loop through each element in the list and apply a filter with a if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quotes to evaluate the local and you need to use commas to separate the values. Here's an example using the auto data.

```
sysuse auto
vallist rep78, sep(,)
tab foreign if inlist(rep78, `r(list)')
```

Comment: Nick, who is the original author of vallist, is giving good programming advice. Just replace "vallist" with "levelsof", and "list" with "levels".

Comment: Huge thanks to both of you.  Nick, thanks again for the advice and guidance on best practices.  `levelsof` is working much quicker

Comment: Just to clear up the different commands and their history, likely to confuse even historians of Stata: `vallist` was first written in 1998 (or perhaps earlier) by me as a user-written add-on  and published in the _Stata Technical Bulletin_ in 2001. There is a version on SSC under Patrick Joly's name, but it has not been touched since 2003. The main functionality was taken over by `levelsof` (briefly called `levels` in Stata 8), which has been part of official Stata since Stata 9 (2005). Bottom line: for almost all purposes, start with `levelsof`.